# How to connect to multiple devices at the same time using adb?

Tags: adb, usb

Things I'm using:

- PC: MacBook Pro (Late 2013), OS X Yosemite version 10.10.4
- USB: ORICO H7928-U2/U3 USB 3.0
- Smartphones: LG G4, Samsung Galaxy Note 2
- ADB version: 1.0.32

I'm trying to connect multiple devices and run at the same time under Eclipse IDE by using ADB, but when I connect two devices, one device status is offline or not listed.

- Connection status:

  ```
  pc right usb port ---------- usb hub ---------------- LG G4
                              └--------------------- galgaxy note2
  ```
- Command line in terminal:

  ```
  nice7285@SJLIMsMacBook13:/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb devices
  adb server is out of date.  killing... 
  * daemon started successfully * 
  List of devices attached  
  LGxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    device
  ```
- Output when disconnecting all devices from USB hub and reconnecting them:

  ```
  nice7285@SJLIMsMacBook13:/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb kill-server 
  nice7285@SJLIMsMacBook13:/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb devices 
  * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 * 
  * daemon started successfully *  
  List of devices attached  
  Galaxyxxxxxxxxxxx    device
  ```

  or

  ```
  nice7285@SJLIMsMacBook13:/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/platform-tools$ ./adb devices 
  * daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *      
  * daemon started successfully * 
  List of devices attached  
  LGxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    offline 
  Galaxyxxxxxxxxxx    offline
  ```

What is best way to connect to multiple devices simultaneously?

Comment: okay check this out, http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26130/4-android-devices-on-a-usb-hub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one example, you have to make the split, it's doesn't seem to be an option,

```
root@kali:# adb devices
List of devices attached 
4fddcdd8054fc421        device
5cf4b0890675d95c        device

root@kali:# export DEVA=4fddcdd8054fc421 && export DEVB=5cf4b0890675d95c

root@kali:# adb -s $DEVA shell uname -a && adb -s $DEVB shell uname -a

Linux localhost 3.4.0-Mina-my-love-53x--gae7828f #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun May 31 00:41:26 EDT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
Linux kali 3.4.0-Mina-my-love-33x--gdba1771-dirty #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Aug 6 18:05:16 EDT 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux
root@kali:#
```

- Export a variable for each device serial.
- `adb -s $VAR1 shell <command> <options> && adb -s $VAR2 shell <command> <options>`

Note this is done without a hub. It might be the hub throwing things off?

Also apparently you dont need to && when exporting/echoing variables

```
root@kali:# export DEVA=4fddcdd8054fc421 DEVB=5cf4b0890675d95c
root@kali:# echo $DEVA $DEVB
4fddcdd8054fc421 5cf4b0890675d95c
```

Comment: Thanks moonbutt74 for your answer, but I 'd like to connect muti devices by using the hub and I think that problem can be solved without export command.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested multi connection with another device (Samsung Galaxy Note4), then it works... :d

I think that the solution may be compatibility between devices or device connection sequence.