# Is it possible to record screens of two android phones connected to a PC?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, adb, android-sdk

I am new to Mobile testing, Recently started using Android adb and started recording device screen using adb shell screenrecord command. Just wanted to know if we can record screens of two android phone at a time connected to a same PC using adb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute `adb help` and notice

```
-s           - directs command to the device or emulator with the given
               serial number or qualifier. Overrides ANDROID_SERIAL
               environment variable.
```

Serial number can be found from `adb devices`. For example,

```
bash-4.X# adb devices
List of devices attached 
543b45da        device
```

`543b45da` (imaginary here) is the serial number for my device.

Serial number can also be found in the output of `adb shell getprop` or the file `build.prop` under `/system`. Look for the term(s) `ro.boot.serialno` or `ro.serialno`.

Now that you've the serial number, simply do

```
adb -s SERIAL_NUMBER YOUR_COMMAND/ADB_ARGUMENT
```

E.g.

```
adb -s 543b45da shell getprop
```

You can execute command(s) for multiple devices from multiple terminals simultaneously. The [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/119140/96277) by moonbutt74 may also help.